# Object Merge Using Base Url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There are urls that I got from the API as objects. Since the names of the objects are different, I need to get them with `Object.values`. I need to combine the value I got with `Object.values` with the base url.

I'm using React-native-slider-image and can't combine strings one by one. All of you should be combined with the same url, but I don't know how many objects will come and what their names will be. Can you please help?

api data is as follows. The number of data varies.

```
"media": {
    "img1": "/static/uploads/photo1.jpg",
    "img2": "/static/uploads/photo2.jpg",
    "img3": "/static/uploads/photo3.jpg"
  },
```

This is how I use a slider. But since only urls come, I need to merge them with the main url.

```
 <SliderBox
           images={Object.values(matchDetails.media)}
  />
```

Comment: Could you please give more details about the expected input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer, but I have some questions too.

What output are you expecting? Is it an array of URLs that look something like "(baseUrl)/static/uploads/photoX.jpg"?

If so you can just do:

```
 <SliderBox
           images={
                Object.values(matchDetails.media)
                   .map(imageUrl => `${baseURl}${imageUrl}`)
           }
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just map the values and append base url in front of that like shown below:

```js
<SliderBox
   images={Object.values(matchDetails.media).map(url => `${BASE_URL}${url}`)}
  />
```